# Create the image file from my boot disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-12.04, dd

I'm trying to create my own image file from the boot disk, so I can import it to google cloud. However, I got an invalid conversion on it. Hope someone can give me some instruction on that. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It would be better for future related searches if you copy/pasted the text instead of providing a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `dd` you have installed may not support the `conv=sparse` option. You may have to upgrade your `coreutils` package to obtain a version of `dd` that supports that option.